# Exit all processes that shell started

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script to run a given number of processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: ./run-abt.sh <agent count> <responder port> <publisher port>
echo "./abt-monitor 127.0.0.1 $2 $3 $1"
exec ./abt-monitor 127.0.0.1 $2 $3 $1 &
for (( i=1; i<=$1; i++ ))
do
    echo "Running agent $i";
    exec ./abt-agent 127.0.0.1 $2 $3 $i $1 > $i.txt &
done
```

What I need to add is when user press `Ctrl+C` and control returns to the bash, all processes created by `run-abt.sh` to kill.

Comment: Note this isn't going to launch any agents: the bash process executing the script will be *replaced* by the abt-monitor process because of the `exec` command. [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec)

Comment: The exec happens in the subshell started by the `&` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to the beginning of your script:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

When your script receives the interrupt signal from the Control-C (or any other signal, for that matter), it will terminate all the child processes before exiting itself.

At the end of the script, add a call to `wait` so that the script itself exit naturally) before the background processes complete, so that the signal handler installed above has a chance to run. That is,

```
for (( i=1; i<=$1; i++ ))
do
    echo "Running agent $i";
    exec ./abt-agent 127.0.0.1 $2 $3 $i $1 > $i.txt &
done    
# There could be more code here. But just before the script would exit naturally,...
wait
```

Comment: How about adding `kill -$$` to the answer as well(that is signalling the whole process group)?

Comment: I'm not sure how standard it is for a negative process ID to represent all processes in the same group as the given process ID. It might be specific to the `/bin/kill` that ships with Linux.

Comment: It's POSIX standard process signaling.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `trap` builtin:

```
trap handler_func SIGINT
```

You'll have to store and manage the pids of the child processes separately, though.

Comment: and grab the pid of a backgrounded process using `$!` variable.